# Open File With Intent (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'd like to open any file (if possible) using an Intent. I have my `openFile(Uri file, String mimeType)` method defined and it's called using a registered BroadcastReceiver. Here is the method:

```
private void openFile(Uri file, String mimeType) {
    Intent openFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    openFile.setData(file);
    try {
        context.startActivity(openFile);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Cannot open file.");
    }
}
```

I'm not currently using `mimeType`, I'm just trying to get this to work. The result of that openFile method when called on a .pdf that has a Uri of `content://downloads/all_downloads/3980` is just a blank pdf opened in the pdf viewer (mime type is probably interpreted correctly) with the 3980 downloadID shown as the filename.

[image: No PDF Displayed]

I know what's happening, in that the content Uri is not being resolved properly for whatever reason. I get the Uri with the line `Uri localUri = downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(downloadId);` where `downloadId` is the long returned from `downloadManager.enqueue(request);`

How do I open a file when I have a content type Uri?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)`. Otherwise, the other app will not have rights to work with the content identified by that `Uri`.

Note that this only works if *you* have rights to work with the content identified by that `Uri`.

Comment: The speed with which this was answered correctly is frustrating. 
I'll mark it as the answer as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: @UnicornMaster: Sorry! I'll... type... more... slowly... next... time... :-)