# Why would an Android Open File intent hang while opening an image?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file

**My Problem:** When `openFile()` intent attempts `StartActivityForResult`, the application hangs with a blank screen and circular cursor. The file(s) are stored to app.

**What I have done:** Before and after this issue I researched how to open files by use of Intents. I found a number of similar but different approaches and either used the literal example or a combination of various examples to see if I could find and resolve the issue (see some below). I'm not receiving any type of error message that I have found, and I had the `FileUriExposedException` previously but resolved it. These files are stored to the app and it may be a permissions issue and have tried what I know, including updating the manifest with  for External Read and Write and added a flag setting on the intent for access.

**What I'm trying to do:** I'm trying to learn how to open files through intents with simple JPG images, then eventually expand to opening various file types after I understand how to do so.

Below is the current code I'm using and it included a MimeTypeMap that I tried in place of "image/jpeg" in case my syntax was not correct on the MIME Type, which did not seem to have an impact.

```java
private void openFile(Uri uri, String fName) {

        MimeTypeMap myMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String mimeType = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(getUpperBound(fName));

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://" + uri), "image/jpeg");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
    }
```

An image of the resulting issue hanging and never opening below:

[image: Hanging Image]

Some of the referenced links I tried:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common

[ACTION_VIEW intent for a file with unknown MimeType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265298/action-view-intent-for-a-file-with-unknown-mimetype)

[Open File With Intent (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42940181/open-file-with-intent-android)

http://www.androidsnippets.com/open-any-type-of-file-with-default-intent.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue combined with S-Sh's second suggestion of considering the use of `FileProvider`. I had to perform some refinements and ended up with the following to work. I also provided links to the sources in which I used.

**Context of the solution:**

As a note to future readers as to the context of this solution within my Android app, the code below is launched by clicking a "clickable" `TableRow` in a `TableLayout`. The TableLayout lists each filename and file ID as a TableRow. Once a row is clicked, the `onClick` method of the selected TableRow the filename is acquired and the `File` class and `FileProvider` are used and filename passed to create an `Uri`. This Uri is then passed to an `openFile(Uri uri)` method I created encapsulating (so-to-speak) the `Intent` used to open the file.

**Code**

**Adding of the FileProvider to the `AndroidManifest.xml' within the`` tag:**

```java
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.mistywillow.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

**Creating within `res` directory the `file_paths.xml` and `xml` directory (res/xml/):**

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <files-path name="myFiles" path="." />
   </paths>
```

**The `onClick` capturing the filename and preparing the Uri to be passed to the openFile():**

```java
    row.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        TableRow tablerow = (TableRow) v;
        TextView sample = (TextView) tablerow.getChildAt(1);
        String result = sample.getText().toString();

        File filePaths = new File(getFilesDir().toString());
        File newFile = new File(filePaths, result);
        Uri contentUri = getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.mydomain.fileprovider", newFile);
        openFile(contentUri);

    });
```

**The `openFile(Uri uri)` method containing the Intent to open a file:**

```java
private void openFile(Uri uri){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(uri);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
}
```

**Links referenced:**

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider

[FileProvider - IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516126/fileprovider-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configured-root)

Answer (score 0):

Try use origin `Uri` itself:

```
 intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
```

Comment: I had started with this but due to the version and that this defaults to the use of "file://...", it is not recommended to be used because it will fail and cause the `FileUriExposedException`. It is suggested to use the parse method to replace the "file://" to  "content://". See: [FileUriExposedException suggested resolution](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException)

Comment: I'm also wondering if there may be a permissions issue that I may not be familiar with. These files are stored in a "file" folder created by the OS and accessible by 'getFileDir().getPath() + /fileName.jpg`.

Comment: You can use a `FileProvider` to share the file. For examle, see this reference: https://infinum.com/the-capsized-eight/share-files-using-fileprovider